# Filter records with current date

Tags: mysql, sql

I am getting stuck in database query. I have a table with two column one for date and other for time.

I want to filter the records with current date time means if only those  records will show those contain the date and time value greater than or equal to current datetime.
Can you please guide in writing this sql query?
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

```
where date > curdate() or
      (date = curdate() and time > curtime())
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to simply concatenate the date and time. In MySQL this is a simple and clear way to generate a date :

```
where CONCAT(date, ' ', time) > NOW()
```

NB : as commented by Juan Carlos Oropeza, this expression does not allow you to use existing indexes on columns `date` and `time` (if any). If you are dealing with a very large amount of data and/or performance critically matters to you, this solution will probably not scale as good as the solution by Gordon Linoff.

Comment: the problem is you can't use index on that filter

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza : corect ; I edited my answer to be explicit about that point. If performance does not matters, I find this expression more explicit (clear) than the other one.

Comment: Then maybe you could change `efficient` for `clear`, that was the word I had problem with.

Answer (score 0):

```
create table Test(id integer, title varchar(100), date DATE , time TIME);

insert into Test(id, title, date, time) values(1, "Date one", '2019-01-01', '01:20:00');
insert into Test(id, title, date, time) values(2, "Date two", '2019-01-02', '11:40:00');
insert into Test(id, title, date, time) values(3, "Date three", '2019-01-03', '23:56:00');
insert into Test(id, title, date, time) values(4, "Date foure", '2019-01-04', '12:20:00');
insert into Test(id, title, date, time) values(5, "Date five", '2019-01-05', '01:20:00');
insert into Test(id, title, date, time) values(6, "Date six", '2019-01-12', '15:47:00');
insert into Test(id, title, date, time) values(7, "Date seven", '2019-01-21', '10:20:00');
insert into Test(id, title, date, time) values(8, "Date eight", '2019-02-01', '01:20:00');


select * from Test WHERE date > '2019-01-04' OR (date = '2019-01-04' AND time >= '10:00:00');
```

Comment: Check Gordon answer. You are removing all days before `10 am`